# displaying an ArrayList in ListView Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist, android-sqlite

I am having difficulty displaying data stored by button clicks that are saved in an SqlLite database into a ListView. It doesn't show the data as i want underneath the button when i click it to add the data to the database.

My code:

```
boolean hasMoreData = cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (hasMoreData) {
        // get the value out of each column
        long key = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDataEntry._ID));
        String studentID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDataEntry.STUDENT_ID_COLUMN));
        String studentGrade = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDataEntry.STUDENT_GRADE_COLUMN));
        //For now, just print out the record to the log.      

        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add( " student id: "+ studentID);
        myList.add(" student grade : " +studentGrade);
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,myList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        System.out.println("RECORD KEY: " + key + " student id: " + studentID + " student grade : " + studentGrade);




        //move on to the next row!
        hasMoreData = cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

what this looks like in emulator :

[current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqeOH.png)

What I want:

[what i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqEbX.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Place a **ArrayAdapter** and **ListView** in outside the loop.

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

boolean hasMoreData = cursor.moveToFirst();
while (hasMoreData) {
    long key = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDataEntry._ID));
    String studentID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDataEntry.STUDENT_ID_COLUMN));
    String studentGrade = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDataEntry.STUDENT_GRADE_COLUMN));

    myList.add( " student id: "+ studentID);
    myList.add(" student grade : " +studentGrade);

    hasMoreData = cursor.moveToNext();
}   
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, myList);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: putting ArrayList<String> myList; above the while loop gives me error in the new ArrayAdapter call for myList not being initalized

Comment: nvm i fixed it by calling new

Comment: this only shows the last grade added it seems for some reason though

Comment: putting ArrayList on top of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();` and `ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>();` you are resetting the list.

Remove `ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();`

and move
`ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);`

above your loop and you'll fix this problem

inside the loop call 'myAdapter.add("whatever you want");' and then `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the ui

Comment: Outside of my loop where exactly? above or below the entry to the while?

Comment: Right above the while loop

Comment: ok, that works for getting all the data. Now my question is, how do i show the data currently added from the button click?

Comment: updated my answer. but EYN's answer is much cleaner ;)